# Draw line after a button pressed in java applet

Tags: java, applet

When i tried this following error came
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

at ButtonTest.actionPerformed(ButtonTest.java:58)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;//step-1
import java.applet.Applet;

public class ButtonTest extends Applet implements ActionListener//step-2
{
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    Font f;
    Graphics gc;
    public void init()
    {
            b1=new Button("Request");
            b2=new Button("Grant");
            b3=new Button("Accept");

            f=new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,12);

            b1.setFont(f);
            b2.setFont(f);
            b3.setFont(f);

            b1.addActionListener(this);
            b2.addActionListener(this);
            b3.addActionListener(this);

            add(b1);
            add(b2);
            add(b3);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics gc) 
    {
        gc.drawLine(100, 150, 100, 400); 
        gc.drawLine(300, 150, 300, 400); 
        gc.drawOval(95, 155, 10, 10);  //1.1
        gc.drawOval(95, 225, 10, 10);  //1.2
        gc.drawOval(95, 295, 10, 10);  //1.3
        gc.drawOval(95, 365, 10, 10);  //1.4
        gc.drawOval(295, 155, 10, 10);  //2.1
        gc.drawOval(295, 225, 10, 10);  //2.2
        gc.drawOval(295, 295, 10, 10);  //2.3
        gc.drawOval(295, 365, 10, 10);  //2.4

    }
    public void myPaint(Graphics gc)  // this line is not working*******???????
                {
                    gc.drawLine(95, 155, 295, 225);  //1.1 to 2.2
                    gc.drawLine(95, 295, 295, 225);  //1.3 to 2.2
                    gc.drawLine(95, 295, 295, 365);  //1.3 to 2.4
                    gc.drawString(">>>", 260, 220); 
                    gc.drawString(">>>", 218, 255);
                    gc.drawString(">>>", 267, 365);
                } 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
            if(ae.getSource()==b1)
            {
                    myPaint(gc);     //this line is not working
                    setBackground(Color.red);

             }
            else if(ae.getSource()==b2)
            {
                 setBackground(Color.green);
            }
            else{
                 setBackground(Color.blue);
            }

     }
}
/*<applet code="ButtonTest" width=300 height=300>
```

### */

error is
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

at ButtonTest.actionPerformed(ButtonTest.java:58)

Comment: What kind of Java do you use. In the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` you define another method `public void paint(Graphics gc)`. This is impossible

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 0):

There a few mistakes in your code. After you have edited your code the line

```
public void myPaint(Graphics gc)
```

works. The line

```
myPaint();
```

does not work because `myPaint` needs an argument of type `Graphics`. The method call should look like

```
myPaint(gc);
```

I don't know what you really want to do, but you can get the canvas of the applet by calling

```
this.getGraphics()
```

There is no need to use `gc` as an argument in `myPaint` or to store Graphic as a member in inside your class.

Hope that helps